# How can I handicap in Suburbia?

Tags: handicap, suburbia

I have Suburbia, and I quite like it. However, some of the people I play with, don't quite have the cutthroat edge to win. It makes not so fun to play if I win every game.

What's an effective way to handicap it?

I was thinking I could simply start with less money, in which case, what would be idea starting amount be?

Comment: Maybe play a different game. 
Also, a general strategy in Suburbia is to favor tiles that raise Income early on, while keeping your reputation low.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, score handicaps are the way to go. You don't have to worry about playing games and experimenting in order to find a balance, you can just use the knowledge you already have of how much you tend to win by.

Money handicap could possibly work, but I think it'd be pretty tough - you only have so much room to adjust before it basically becomes a "you have waste one early turn to build a lake right away" handicap.

That said, you can also just not make the handicap formal: try to do the best you can every game, and accept the fact that you're striving for a larger margin of victory instead of worrying about winning.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to handicap the premium costs for early development

This could be implemented for stronger players as:

- +$1 or +$2 for every spot
- +$1 or +$2 for every spot except the last free spot
- +$1 or +$2 for every spot except both free spots

Or for weaker players as

- $1 or $2 less for every spot
- $1 or $2 less for every spot except the last free spot
- $1 or $2 less for every spot except both free spots

Pick one of these.  I think it would be simplest